# my render is cropped

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error

since version 3.0 some of my projects start to make a kind of cut in the upper and right edges of my render (visible in the example image), this doesn't happen in every project but when it happens it's very annoying because I don't know how to solve it, in this case the background is transparent but when I use backgrounds and the image is a png, the area is tanparency[image: exemplo]

Comment: Your object may be too large, try scaling it down.

Comment: pls provide blend file